# Google ads conversion isn't matching with GA4

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api, google-analytics-4

I have configured the Google ads conversions with GTM. Google ads conversions are high when compared to GA4. GA4 is linked to the Google ads account but was set as secondary. Primary conversion is configured with GTM. I know there will be bit discrepancies but I am facing a huge difference.

Google Ads configured via GTM and GA4 is linked with Google Ads. However, I am seeing higher conversions in Google ads for purchase and low conversion value in GA4 when I select source/ medium revenue.

Answer (score 1):

GA4 will attribute each conversion to one source/medium.

However, advertising channels will take the attribution if they were involved in  the users journey within a specific time period.

e.g. a user clicked on a Goog Ad, then a Facebook ad, then visits via Google search. GA4 will pick one of them. While all the channels will take credit for it themselves.

This means each channel will report higher numbers than what GA4 attributed to them.